# How to Update ESRI Leaflet Attribution Panel

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leftlet and creating a Map Like this

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([54.793577, -126.687482], 6); 
 L.esri.basemapLayer('NationalGeographic').addTo(map);
```

now can you please let me know how I can update the leaflet-control-attribution 
to display the following information

```
 attribution: '© Thesite contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
```

I tried this way

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([54.793577, -126.687482], 6, {attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'});
```

but it didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the attribution control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution) will show you how:

```
map.attributionControl.addAttribution('© Thesite contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ' );
```